# I use some code, then I use it again in a loop. It looks ugly, is there a way to improve it?

Tags: c#

I started learning c#. I wrote a simple guess the number program. It works, but I use some code before a loop then I reuse it in the loop. There must be a better way.

```
using System;

namespace Guessthenumber
{
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        string guess;
        int yourguess;
        int dice = rnd.Next(1, 7);
        Console.WriteLine("Guess a number between 1 and 6");
        guess = Console.ReadLine();
        yourguess = int.Parse(guess);
```

Here comes the pattern that I repeat again in the loop. Is there a way to avoid this?

```
        if (yourguess > dice)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Lower");
        }
        if (yourguess < dice)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Higher");
        }
        if (yourguess == dice)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Correct!");
        }
        while (yourguess != dice)
        {


          guess = Console.ReadLine();
          yourguess = int.Parse(guess);
            if (yourguess > dice)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Lower");
            }
            if (yourguess < dice)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Higher");
            }
            if (yourguess == dice)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Correct!");
            }

        }
        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Probably better to ask this question on the code review stack exchange site: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know  there was a special section for that

Comment: I hope someone suggests some improvements anyway. But now I know where to ask the next time.

Comment: It's tough to know where to post programming questions sometimes because there are quite a few off-shoots from stackoverflow that target certain types of questions. Usually there is a bit of leniency on this site (even though the question may be migrated later). All that aside, I'm glad to see you got the answer you were looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `do, while` loop instead of the `while`. That way, the code becomes:

```
static void Main()
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    string guess;
    int yourguess;
    int dice = rnd.Next(1, 7);
    Console.WriteLine("Guess a number between 1 and 6");
    do
    {
        guess = Console.ReadLine();
        yourguess = int.Parse(guess);

        if (yourguess > dice)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Lower");
        }
        if (yourguess < dice)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Higher");
        }
        if (yourguess == dice)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Correct!");
        }
    } while (yourguess != dice);

    Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Thanks that looks much better!

Comment: just needed a ; after } while (yourguess != dice) then it worked like intended :)

Comment: @PatrikGustafsson, obviously I deliberately made that mistake to ensure it wasn't too easy for you ;). Thanks for pointing out my typo; I've updated the answer to correct it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use a [`do-while loop`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/370s1zax.aspx) instead:

```
do
{
    // Repeated stuff
} while (yourguess != dice);
```